# how to get all value checkbox when next pagination (jsp and servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I am using a display list Url Crawler for pagination in my JSP page,  I have a checkbox field as one of the columns.The problem i have is, i will loose the status of the checkbox when i go to second page. If i select some of the checkboxes in page 1 and go to page 2 to select some more and if i come back, i loose all the selected checkboxes in page 1.

Using servlet:

```
ArrayList<String> listUrlCheckBox = new ArrayList<>();
    if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
        String[] checkBoxMutil = request
                .getParameterValues("monitoringUrl");
        if (checkBoxMutil != null) {
            for (String s : checkBoxMutil) {
                listUrlCheckBox.add(s);
            }
        }
   }
```

Jsp page

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="monitoringUrl" class="checkbox" value="<%=listUrl.getNameUrl()%>" /></td>
```

Image for interface
  [image]

Will be glad if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

When is your code being called? On a submission of sorts or after each pagination? What you could do is have your servlet read each checkbox value on each pagination and store the values in a request object or a session object. On the final submission, just read from said object.